# Proof of uniform convergence of an infinite product

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence, infinite-product

I am reading the book [Complex Analysis: An Invitation (2nd Edition), page 163-164](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9814579580). There is a certain step in the proof, which I can not fill the details. First, I mention a relevant proposition and a definition.

**Proposition**: The infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_k)$ converges if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|<\infty$, and in that case
$$
  \left | \prod_{k=1}^\infty (1+a_k)-1 \right |\leq e^{\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|}-1 \tag{*}
$$

**Definition**: Let $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of complex valued functions defined in an open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{C}$. We say that the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_k)$ **converges locally uniformly** in $\Omega$, if $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_k(z))$ converges at each $z\in \Omega$ and if furthermore to each compact subset $K$ of $\Omega$ and each $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $z\in K$ and $n\geq N$
$$
\left | \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+a_k(z))-\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_k(z)) \right |<\epsilon.
$$

What I want to prove is:

> **Lemma**: Let $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of complex valued functions on an open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{C}$. If as $N\to\infty$ the sum $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|a_n(z)|$ converges locally uniformly to $0$, then the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_k)$ converges locally uniformly in $\Omega$.

The proof which the author says is simply: "It is a consequence of Proposition and the inequality (*)" It does not seem completely clear to me. Could someone explain that step for me?

**Update**: When I read the answer of Kavi Rama Murthy, I thought as follows: Let $K$ be any compact subset of $\Omega$, and let $\epsilon\in (0,1/2)$ be given. Choose an integer $N^*$ with $N^*\geq N$ such that $\sum_{n=n+1}^{\infty}|a_n(z)|<\epsilon$ for all $z\in K$ and all $n\geq N^*$. Then, we have for all $z\in K$ and all $n\geq N^*$
$$
\left | \prod_{k=n+1}^\infty (1+a_k(z))-1 \right |\leq e^{\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty |a_k(z)|}-1<e^\epsilon - 1<2\epsilon
$$
and so
$$
\left | \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+a_k(z))-\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_k(z)) \right |=\left | \prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_k(z)) \right |\left | \prod_{k=n+1}^{\infty}(1+a_k(z))-1 \right |<2\epsilon \left | \prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_k(z)) \right |.
$$
Then I got stuck here.

Comment: I'd like to help but I don't know what  "Proposition and the inequality (*)" is. I don't have the book.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet They are stated in the beginning of the post. I think I have figured out the proof, but thanks for trying to help. If you want and have time, could you please see my other [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4401936/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|\prod_{k=n}^{m}(1+a_k(z))-1|\leq e^{ \sum\limits_{k=n}^{m}|a_k(z)}-1$. On any compact set $K$ we can choose $N$ such that $e^{ \sum\limits_{k=n}^{m}|a_k(z)}-1<\epsilon$ for alll $z \in K$ fro all $n,m \geq N$. Now consider $|\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_k(z))-\prod_{k=1}^{m}(1+a_k(z))|$ where $n <m$. We can write this as $|\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_k(z))| |\prod_{k=n+1}^{m}(1+a_k(z))-1|$. What remains is to see that th first factor $\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_k(z))$ is uniformly bounded on $K$. This follows by another application of (*). I hope you can finish.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have made an update of my post, where I wrote the way I understood of the proof, inspired by your answer. Though there is still one more step I could not complete. Could you please read, what you think of my proof?

Comment: @Mr.MathDoctor $\left | \prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_k(z)) \right |\leq 1+(e^{\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k(z)}-1)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k(z)$ is bounded on $K$, right?

Comment: That was my initial thought, but then I thought it might depend on $z$, wouldn't it? Is it because that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k(z)|$ is uniformly convergent on $K$, it must be bounded there?

Comment: @Mr.MathDoctor There exists $N$ such that $|\sum\limits_{k=N}^{\infty} a_k(z)|<1$ for all $z \in K$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I think I should add an extra assumption in the lemma, that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is of **bounded** complex valued functions, otherwise it is not known whether the rest of function terms $a_1(z),..., a_{N-1}$ are bounded or not, yet the sum of all other terms is bounded, right?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and your valuable time. I figured out the proof. If you have time, could you please check my another post concerning the convergence of infinite products? See this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4401936/).